# Why is an if statement triggering without the parameters present being true?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, mouse

I've just come across a situation in which an if statement is constantly triggering despite the parameters not being true.

```
function draw(){
 if(5<mouseX<10 && 5<mouseY<10){
      background(100);
    } else (background(200));
}
```

When running the above program, the background is always value 100, no matter where I move the mouse.

I've boiled this down from an attempt to make a button within a `mouseClicked` function in a successful attempt to find my fundamental problem of misunderstanding. I'm running it in p5js if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if-statement` should be as follows:

```
if(5<mouseX && mouseX<10 && 5<mouseY && mouseY<10)
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind this behaviour is:

```
 if(5<mouseX<10 && 5<mouseY<10){
      background(100);
    } else (background(200));
```

When the javascript engine reads `5<mouseX` it returns true then reads `true<10` this is also `true` as here the js engine treats true as `1` and condition `1<10` is always true. This happens with other part of the expression also.

Try using :

```
if(5<mouseX && mouseX<10 && 5<mouseY && mouseY<10)
```